# Source Insight Reset Windows Layout

Tags: visual-studio, source-insight

Is there any way of setting the Windows layouts to default in Source Insight.I mean how can I do the "Reset Windows layout" as in Visual Studio in Source Insight?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the late response,  I just saw this question today (October 3).

You may have already figured this out,  but let me answer just in case not.

Yes, there is a way to reset the window layout.   It is detailed at:

http://www.sourceinsight.com/faq35.html

See the section on that page with title "Context Window"

Essentially you explicitly store your configuration to a file, delete Source Insight's configuration file, and then reload you stored configuration file with options set to exclude window information.

A bit kludgy, but it does the trick.

I've written a PowerShell script to do the work, which makes it a little less of a kludge.